# Looking for a fully customisable WP responsive theme to develop a small scale fiverr type site for voice artists

Tags: themes

I'm new here, not totally wet behind the ears but in reality, a beginner.
I am looking for a free, fully customisable WP theme to develop a fiverr type site for voice artists but on a much smaller scale. I'm thinking of limiting membership to 3000 to begin, including buyers and talent - if interest is shown.

I will need a lot of help as this is quite a bit to chew off but I'm determined.
I just need a good starting point - a theme (I think), unless anyone has any other suggestions.
It would need to be able to handle lots of uploading of mp4, mp3, jpeg, png, buying and selling with Paypal, Escrow etc.

Security is of utmost importance.

Anyone have any solid advice on which theme I could use that is user friendly?
I am using XAMP.

Thank youin advance for any feedback!

All the best!

Comment: maybe research microjob plugins, a theme is not really for functionality like this (though there might be one with that included, best to try to keep function and design separate.)

Comment: Your advice is invaluable and most appreciated. Microjob is perfect and just what I'm looking for! Thanks once again!

Comment: groovy. glad I could help!